# How could the uncountable noun "sufferings" be plural?

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

We know that there is no plural form of the "uncountable noun," but, for example, we write:

> His sufferings force us to retain pity for him.

Is it possible to make an uncountable noun plural? If so, please explain it.

Comment: What makes you think "sufferings" are uncountable?

Comment: then?countable?but how sir?

Comment: Why do **you** think it's **not** countable?

Comment: because we cant count our suffering.

Comment: Sure we can. "Right now I am dealing with two sufferings: a headache and a heartache." It's not exactly standard anymore, but it's perfectly correct. See also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sufferings

Comment: My clothes doesn't fit me.

Comment: It's always wrong to take *a life* because *life* is precious. *The lives* of many have been cut short. That being said, how lucky are cats to have *nine lives*?

Comment: Behold an [enumerated list of sufferings](http://www.catholic.org/prayers/prayer.php?p=248)!

Comment: @Kevin Workman – Can you find a modern authority licensing 'sufferings' as a count noun rather than a mass noun taking a plural verb? 'Two sufferings' doesn't sound 'perfectly correct' to me.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It doesn't really matter whether it "sounds" correct to you. It is correct. It's a little old-fashioned, as I already said, but consult your nearest dictionary for "sufferings".

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/when-can-you-pluralize-uncountable-nouns?rq=1) which was auto-flagged as related.

Comment: @Kevin Workman: I've managed to find some examples of what must be count noun usages of 'sufferings'. But they are niche usages. Dictionaries are usually inadequate on differentiating, not flagging plural-form mass nouns such as clothes, entrails, guts = bottle _as_ mass nouns. Here, 'sufferings' = 'trials and tribulations' would rarely be discretely quantified (??7 sufferings / ??4 trials and tribulations / *3 trials and 6 tribulations) and so is being used as a mass noun (taking plural agreement). Cf his clothes are threadbare / *His 7 clothes are threadbare.

Answer (score 13):

"[W]e know that there is no plural form of 'uncountable noun' ..."

*Do we really*?

[I'm taking this preamble to read 'we know that mass nouns are always singular' in line with the statement below: ' ... the idea that mass nouns are always singular has been part of conventional wisdom ever since Bloomfield (1933)'.]

Peter Lasersohn, in [*Mass Nouns and Plurals*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F214750278_Mass_nouns_and_plurals%2Ffile%2F9fcfd50bf9e04d9c84.pdf&ei=hdaMU-uUL43nsATqsoJ4&usg=AFQjCNEdkNmQEEdptJNJQPfEQrz-Bz1N_w&sig2=qE9PrOknHrBpIEkBnMTnSg), writes:

> [One] issue is whether the term 'mass' should be understood broadly
> enough to include some morphologically plural examples. Jespersen
> argued that a wide range of plural nouns were actually mass, including
> examples such as
>
> victuals, oats, brains (in the sense exemplified in blow out
> somebody’s brains), dregs, lees, proceeds, measles, mumps, hysterics,
> blues, creeps, and others.
>
> We may note that these impose plural agreement on the verb, but (under
> the relevant reading) combine with much rather than many:
>
> (8) a. In this kind of work, brains are less important than guts.
>
> b. It doesn’t take much brains to figure this out.
>
> Here again Bloomfield (1933) introduced a shift in terminology,
> stipulating that mass nouns “have no plural,” without providing
> discussion of Jespersen’s examples; the idea that mass nouns are
> always singular has been part of conventional wisdom ever since.
>
> Plural mass nouns have been periodically rediscovered ([McCawley 1975](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_Ccg-TGBRj8C&pg=PA535&lpg=PA535&dq=Plural+mass+nouns++McCawley+1975&source=bl&ots=KCoEmZc2Dj&sig=klm1scZM4FEDT3I9g0MHrXnrt8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ccSMU5bIAbOzsATpi4HoDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Plural%20mass%20nouns%20%20McCawley%201975&f=false),
> [Gillon 1992](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JskLROQX1v4C&pg=PA394&lpg=PA394&dq=Plural+mass+nouns+Gillon+1992&source=bl&ots=1b4TKkQojd&sig=Wcmo6qSgfMDsxcuvTRfsEzCvqq0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TsWMU-v5EO7MsQTls4LgCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Plural%20mass%20nouns%20Gillon%201992&f=false) ), and are treated in detail in [Ojeda (2005)](http://linguistics.ucdavis.edu/People/fzojeda/linguistics-papers/paradox_mass_plurals.pdf). Some authors
> (e.g. Gleason 1965: 135) consider such examples to be neither count
> nor mass, but a third category.
>
> Even if we recognize some morphologically plural examples as mass
> nouns, it should be noted that they, like morphologically singular
> mass nouns, lack a number distinction; in these examples it is simply
> the singular which is “missing” rather than the plural.

I don't think that anyone would reckon the noun *clothes*, which takes a plural verb, to be a count noun. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) [tidied] comments:

> mass nouns such as "water" or "furniture", with which only singular
> verb forms are used : the constituent matter is handled in a
> grammatically nondiscrete way (although it may ["water"] or may not
> ["furniture"] be etically nondiscrete)

And, though garments can be counted and so 'clothes' is etically discrete, it is not handled as a typical count noun accepting numerals.

Although there are rare examples of '**sufferings**' (as indeed for 'furnitures' and 'waters') which show true count behaviour (eg 'The Three Sufferings – Balanced Holistic Weight Management'), the plural mass-noun usage equivalent to 'what he has gone / is going through' is far more common and is almost certainly the intended usage here. Consider: one would do a double-take on seeing say "three trials and tribulations".

Comment: There are a lot of varieties of noun, and Mass/Count is not really an open/shut matter. [Massification and countification](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111365/15299) are both quite common.

Comment: Nothing in your answer says anything about plural forms of uncountable nouns. If you think that *sufferings* is not the plural form of the uncountable noun *suffering*, but rather is simply a plural uncountable noun unto itself, then you should say so (and delete your misleading first few sentences); without such a statement, I don't think this actually answers the question.

Comment: @ ruakh: I thought that McCawley, Gillon and Ojeda, and Jespersen (who 'argued that a wide range of plural nouns were actually mass') might be more persuasive than myself. Though I do certainly think that they, and not Bloomfield, are correct here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not sure what your point is. McCawley, Gillon and Ojeda, and Jespersen are not saying anything about plural forms of uncountable nouns; rather, they're talking about nouns that are both plural and uncountable. The distinction is fundamental, and the OP was asking about the former (or thought (s)he was).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Ah, O.K., I now see your edit. I disagree with your inference, but making it explicit makes this a bunch better answer; thanks.

Comment: @ ruakh Before one starts trying to distinguish between 'plural forms of uncountable nouns' and 'nouns that are both plural and uncountable', one has to define plural forms of nouns, uncountable nouns, and plural nouns. Ojeda spells out the problem: 'clothes' [being both 'a mass noun' and 'a plural noun'] is ... an embarrassment for semantic theory. ... In short, clothes should refer to discrete entities taken in bulk rather than collectively and, at the same time, to discrete entities taken collectively 
rather than in bulk. This embarrassing predicament is the paradox of mass plurals.

Comment: [Wikipedia]: 'In linguistics, a mass noun or uncountable noun is a noun with the syntactic property that any quantity of it is treated as an undifferentiated unit, rather than as something with discrete subsets.' BUT '... mass nouns such as furniture and cutlery, which represent more easily quantified objects, show that the mass/count distinction should be thought of as a property of the terms themselves, rather than as a property of their referents.'>> We could start by distinguishing 'nouns specifying >1 discrete referents' from 'nouns taking a plural verb'.

Comment: Right, as plural nouns lacking inflectional singulars, *my clothes are* and *my cattle are* are categorically different because just as you can say that *some of your cattle are*, you can also say *one of my cattle is* by making a periphrastic singular: it's as easy to count cattle as sheep. But you can no more do that with your clothes than you can with your clothing.  They strongly resist any attempt to do anything to them that involves counts, whether singular or plural. You cannot say two of your clothes or two of your clothing, nor can you say one of your clothes or one of your clothing.

Comment: @tchrist This makes [will the usage accept any numeral?] + [will the usage accept large round numerals?] + ['will the usage accept _one/two of my_?'] + ['is the noun as used in singular or plural form, or grey?'] + [is a singular or plural (or both) verb form/s used with this usage?] + [can you count the referents?] so far, by my reckoning.

Answer (score 5):

> "While uncountable nouns do not generally take a plural form,
>   sometimes they may be pluralized when used in a countable
>   sense."[**](http://easenglish.net/Files/Grammar/uncountable%20words.pdf)

Uncountable nouns are *usually singular,* but not always. It's not a catch-all rule by any means, especially when discussing abstract nouns used in the *countable sense.* Take this example:

> He has sympathy for **the sufferings** of his fellow countrymen.

You can't quantify the suffering of each countryman. Thus, you can't quantify the sufferings of the countrymen either. Nonetheless, each *one* suffers. So, when the countrymen are considered as a whole, *each one's suffering* amounts to *their sufferings.*

Though general rules regarding the countable/uncountable distinction are valid, there are many exceptions and the context is important. Here's a good example:

> **It's always wrong to take *a life*** [countable singular] **because *life*** [uncountable singular] **is precious. *The lives*** [uncountable plural] **of many have been sadly cut short. That
>   being said, how lucky are cats to have *nine lives*** [countable plural]**?**

Comment: No. This confuses terminology, and analysis. It only makes sense to analyse usages, not nouns, as count or non-count. Many if not all nouns used normally in non-count contexts may be countified. Also, 'data' say is _plural-form_ but usually _singular in construction_ (as is 'confetti'); it is unhelpful to label these either just 'plural' or 'singular'.